# Neo4j - Get relationship graph after aggregation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am brand new to CQL and I have tried several ways to get the graph working for my query in the browser. When I run the query below, I am able to successfully get aggregated table however not the graph with nodes and relationship for p and g. I have tried many 'RETURN' syntax, it doesn't graph. How do I visualize person_name and company_name?

Working Table:

```
MATCH (p:person_name)-[m:WORKS_AT]->(g:company_name)
with p,count(g) as cnt
where cnt > 1
RETURN p.name,cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Tried:

```
MATCH (p:person_name)-[m:WORKS_AT]->(g:company_name)
with p,count(g) as cnt
where cnt > 1
RETURN type(m) # Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `m` not defined 

RETURN p.name,cnt # shows table 

RETURN p,g # Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `g` not defined

RETURN (p)-[m]->(g) # Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `m`

RETURN (p)-[r]->(g) # Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `r`

RETURN * # gives only person_name nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

The visualizer will only show returned nodes, relationships, and paths. You're returning a property of a node, not the node itself, so nothing will show up in the visualizer.

You could try this query instead, which filters :person_name nodes by the degree of :WORKS_AT relationships, and then matches to the pattern and returns the nodes and relationships found:

```
MATCH (p:person_name)
WITH p, size((p)-[:WORKS_AT]->()) as degree
WHERE degree > 1
MATCH (p)-[m:WORKS_AT]->(g:company_name)
RETURN p, degree, m, g
ORDER BY degree DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used your query from above, unfortunately it returns nothing. `(no changes, no records)`

Comment: Okay, next step is to figure out why. Try this: `MATCH (p:person_name)
RETURN p, size((p)-[:WORKS_AT]->()) as degree ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10`. That should show if you have any :person_name nodes that have more than one :WORKS_AT relationship.

Comment: You can also PROFILE the query and look at how the rows change between operations. Find out where in the plan the rows drop to 0, and inspect the surrounding operations to figure out at which point in the query that happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (p:person_name)-[m:WORKS_AT]->(g:company_name)
with p,count(g) as cnt, g
where cnt > 1
RETURN p.name, g 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```